# relatório em tabelas relacionadas (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

galera, to me quebrando numa coisa super simples, mas nao sei onde to errando

Digamos que eu tenha as tabelas abaixo, todas relacionadas entre si

```
tabela1: nota_fiscal (id, data_emissao)
1 '2019-05-12'
2 '2019-02-02'
3 '2019-05-05'

tabela2: itens (id, descricao)
1 'vestuario'
2 'comida'

tabela3: notafiscal_itens (id_nf, id_itens, valor_total)
1 2 50.00
1 1 100.00
2 2 70.00
```

> preciso fazer um select com um SUM (valor_total) da tabela
>   notafiscal_itens, WHERE id_itens = 2 AND notafiscal.data_emissao
>   between ('2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31')

como ficaria esse select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testa esse código e ve se da certo, e testa sem o GROUP BY e ve se da certo mesmo assim.

```
select SUM(nfi.valor_total)
from notafiscal_itens as as nfi
inner join notafiscal as nf on nf.id = nfi.id_nf
WHERE nfi.id_itens = 2
AND nf.data_emissao between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY valor_total
```

Comment: bem certinho, valeu, sem o group by deu exatamente o que eu precisva, tava errando no inner join